# Line graph from dataframe, the last tick is not visible

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a line graph with dataframe but the last tick is not visible. What should I do to make the last tick is visible?

[image]

```
line_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': value
}, index=date)


line_df.plot.line(figsize=(10,7), legend=None)
```

Comment: For a start, you can provide [a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you using a recent matplotlib and pandas version?